# Is the function 1 - x a bijection from [0,1] to [0,1)

Tags: number-theory, functions

I want to prove the set [0,1] is equinumerous to [0,1) I came up with 1 - x 
I can prove it's bijective, but I was curious if this might be too simple of a function.

Comment: $x\mapsto1-x$ is not a function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1)$.

Comment: Why do you think it's a bijection? Let's start with that and work our way through...

Comment: What value does it take for $x=0$?

Comment: You don't need to give an explicit bijection to show that they are equinumerous.

Comment: Ok here is what I came up with.         it gets mapped to itself if x doesn't equal 1/2^n and if x does equal 1/2^n then the function becomes 1/2^(n+1) that way it works for 1, and it works for 1/2 etc and keeps going.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not well defined at $0$, so it cannot be a bijection. At $0$, the value of the function should be $f(0)=1$, however this is absurd as $1\notin [0,1)$.

To prove find a real bijection, I would advise you to simply start with $f(x)=x$, and then "fix" the problem of $f(1)$ so the function maps $1$ to some other number $x_1$ in $[0,1)$. Then, fix the problem of $f(x_1)$, and repeat.

Comment: In particular, you could simply use the sequence of powers of 2; $f(2^{-n}) = 2^{-n-1}$, and otherwise $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Ok here is what I came up with. it gets mapped to itself if x doesn't equal 1/2^n and if x does equal 1/2^n then the function becomes 1/2^(n+1) that way it works for 1, and it works for 1/2 etc and keeps going. –